# Read-only error on lxle dual boot with windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, copy-and-paste

Tried disabling the fast boot option in Windows 10 also tried shift+shutdown but still it refuses to give me access to paste files

Into Windows 10. The paste option is grayed out giving me

"Read-only" error.

sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sda2 /mnt/windows returned:

> Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
> Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
> unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
> or fast restarting.)
> ntfs-3g-mount: failed to access mountpoint /mnt/windows: No such file or directory

Obviously this issue is related to the Windows 10 shutdown process.

I tried both force shutdown and changing the system registry settings but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the hibernation feature, helped to resolve the issue.

First disable the fast boot option:

> Go to Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > System Settings Then click on 'Change Settings that are currently unavailable' and remove tick from 'Turn on fast startup'.

Run this with elevated prompt:

> powercfg /h off

and then restart your computer for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Great to see you solved it and posted the answer, thanks.